# らしい / っぽい / みたい question: Why 黒{くろ}っぽい車{くるま} and not 黒{くろ}みたいな車{くるま}?

Tags: grammar, jlpt

I'm using Nihongo So-Matome 文法{ぶんぽう} while preparing for JLPT N3, and having some issues with some of the grammar descriptions.

This StackExchange answer was awesome in clearing up most of my らしい / っぽい / みたい questions:

[Contrasting っぽい、らしい、みたい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/contrasting-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BD%E3%81%84%E3%80%81%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E3%80%81%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

However, this one remains - why is it OK to say:

逃{に}げたのは**黒{くろ}っぽい**車{くるま}でした。

But not:

逃{に}げたのは**黒{くろ}みたいな**車{くるま}でした。

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Axioplase's answer to the question you linked expresses the nuance.

- `っぽい`: '-ish'. Can be used for an attribute, or resemblance.

> 黒っぽい車　[attribute]
>    'a blackish car'
>
> 霊{れい}柩{きゅう}車{しゃ}っぽい車  [resemblance]
>    'a hearse-ish car'

- `みたい`: 'like'. Can be used for resemblance, but not for an attribute.

> × 黒みたいな車　[attribute]
>    　'a car that is like black'
>
> 霊柩車みたいな車  [resemblance]
>    　'a car that is like a hearse'

Comment: Sawa, this is just the answer I needed - with some more extrapolation I might have figured the answer out from Axioplase's comment, but your explanation is much clearer, thanks! "Can be used for resemblance, but not for an attribute."