# what is the difference beween おんなみたい、おんならしい　and　おんなっぽい。

Tags: grammar, words

what is the difference beween おんなみたい、おんならしい　and　おんなっぽい。
could any one please clear the difference between them with example.

Comment: This question has already been asked [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/contrasting-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BD%E3%81%84%E3%80%81%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E3%80%81%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84).

Comment: It does appear to be an exact duplicate.  I thought there might already be a question about みたい, らしい and ぽい, but I didn't think there'd be a question specifically about おんなみたい, おんならしい, and おんなっぽい!